# Importing C python module in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, import, cpython

I am developing an application on Google app engine using Python. I want to use editdist feature of Python and for that reason I am importing editdist C python module in my program, but it is showing that module editdist does not exist.

When I import editdist for my local application it is working fine but not for Google app engine application.

Can anyone suggest me a method to import this module?

Answer (score 5):

App Engine is a "[pure python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python)" environment, and you cannot use any C extensions or other code that must be compiled.

There is therefore no way to use *this* program on App Engine, and all of the competing "production quality" python libraries I found were implemented as C modules.

There do exist [alternate implementations of the Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python), though none are as nearly as fast as editdist.  These more naïve implementations might still be acceptable depending upon your needs.

Comment: Is there any module which I can use directly instead of using my own implementation? And I think App Engine do support C extensions but to a certain limit only, this can be checked here http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/libraries.html

Comment: @user617462: They support C libraries that are part of the standard library and already included with the python runtime they're using.  You cannot use your own C libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here could be couple alternatives that are implemented with Python (I haven't tested them myself):

- http://www.korokithakis.net/node/87
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576874-levenshtein-distance/